# Responsive design order in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, css, rwd

I've just created a new theme that extends from Magento Blank, and within the file _theme.less I did something like this:

```
h1 {
  font-size: 24px;
}  

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  h1 {
    font-size: 18px;
  }  
}

@media (max-width: 480px) {
  h1 {
    font-size: 12px;
  }  
}
```

However, the mobile styles are not being applied. I opened the styles-m.css source code and I found out that the desktop styles are at the bottom, overriding all of the styles above them.

```
@media (max-width: 480px) {
  h1 {
    font-size: 12px;
  }  
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  h1 {
    font-size: 18px;
  }  
}

h1 {
  font-size: 24px;
}
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should build your media queries the proper way the Magento UI library expects it as Magento will build a style file for mobile (styles-m.css) and for desktop devices (styles-l.css). I think the issues you currently experience can be traced back to this. You should also approach this in a mobile-first manner. Try this:

```
.media-width(@extremum, @break) when (@extremum = 'max') and (@break = @screen__xs) {
  h1 {
    font-size: 12px;
  }  
}

.media-width(@extremum, @break) when (@extremum = 'max') and (@break = @screen__m) {
  h1 {
    font-size: 18px;
  }  
}

.media-width(@extremum, @break) when (@extremum = 'min') and (@break = @screen__m) {
  h1 {
    font-size: 24px;
  }  
}
```

This way, the default size is 12px for small mobile devices, everything which is wider than 480px will have 18px and devices wider than 768px will be size 24px. These sizes are defined in `lib/web/css/source/lib/variables/_responsive.less`. You should definitely read the [developer guide](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/responsive-web-design/rwd_css.html) on the matter to understand how to effectively use these queries.

Also, make sure Magento 2 is set to development mode!

Comment: I think the first use of `.media-width` won't work, as it isn't defined in the original `_responsive.less` file of Magento 2.

Comment: It definitely works, it's defined in `lib/web/css/source/lib/_responsive.less` and inherited from that file.

Comment: The only `@extremum = 'min'` defined is for `@screen__s` (for mobile target). The others are defined with `@extremum = 'max'`. I tried this code, but the case `when (@extremum = 'min') and (@break = @screen__xs)` doesn't appear in the code.

Comment: You're right! I did not re-read my own response properly because it's over a year old and this slipped my mind back then. I have updated the code so that now it shows what would need to be done in order for it to work as expected in this example.

Answer (score -2):

You can use `!important` or you can make a seperate css file then declare it in `app/frontend/Your_Vendor/Your_theme/Magento_Theme/layout/default_head_blocks.xml` like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
        <head>
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no"/>
            <css src="css/your_css_file.css" />
        </head>
</page>
```

and your css file location is: `app/frontend/Your_Vendor/Your_theme/web/css/your_css_file.css`

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I know I can use !important, but it shouldn't be necessary. I think I'm missing something related with @media-common or something like that.